# Extracting Data Logically from Unstructured Text

Tags: nlp

Best method for parsing unstructured texts like below using NLP? Would a model be the best solution to this? If so, what would be the best way to start?

```
Prerequisite: Mathematics 408C and 408D with a grade of a C, and Physics 301 or 301K with a grade of a C.
```

which would result in something like

```
Mathematics 408C C, Mathematics 408D C, Physics 301 C or Physics 301 C
```

I've tried using just regex, but the sentence structure can be a lot more complex and inconsistent. Like below

```
Prerequisite: Architecture 415K with a grade of at least C; Mathematics 408C or 408K; and Physics 302K and 102M, or 303K and 103M.
```

Desired Result:

```
Architecture 415K C, Mathematics 408C or Mathematics 408K, Physics 302K and Physics 102M or Physics 303K and Physics 103M
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input texts are not really natural language (full sentences containing information) but rather a semi-structured and therefore difficult to handle for both rule-based and semantics-based approaches.

A semantic/neural-model based approach like using a pre-trained Question Answering model in huggingface (python/PyTorch) might be a bit ouf of the box here but it could help to give some structure which is almost independent from previous structure:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Benefit of this approach is that is basically independent of the input structure, see for example an [input with full sentences](https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2?context=To%20take%20part%20in%20this%20course%20students%20should%20have%20finished%20Mathematics%20408C%20and%20408D%20with%20at%20least%20a%20C%2C%20and%20Physics%20301%20or%20301K%20with%20at%20least%20a%20C.&question=Which%20grade%20is%20required%20for%20Physics%20301%20or%20301K%3F) or a [bullet point list](https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2?context=Prerequisites%3A-%20Mathematics%20%28408C%20and%20408D%29%20-%3E%20grade%20C-%20Physics%20%28301%20or%20301K%29%20-%3E%20grade%20C&question=Which%20grade%20is%20required%20for%20Physics%20301%20or%20301K%3F).

Since the model only returns valid output if the question is clearly answerable from the context you would have to use a rule-based approach to get the list of Courses mentioned in the prerequisites, and then use the first answer to create a valid question for the grade.

But I honestly wonder how many possible ways to write there are for such a list. Also how much effort you want to put into this if this is just a handful of texts. If you show some more examples we can discuss possible rule-based approaches.

Comment: Definitely, here are some more examples @ [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/e2sdqsPA). I'm confused though when you mention using a rule-based approach to get the list of courses. Would the list be the context for the question/answer model?

Comment: This question answering model is trained on using single sentences/short texts as context and extract a single information from them. So handing the entire list to it would probably be too much to handle for the model. Hand a single Prerequisite field to it as shown in the images.

Comment: Well the thing about a question answering model is that it will never perfectly work in every case and might produce some unexpected results as it uses semantics, so the inner workings are basically a black box. I can imagine that for some basic cases a rule-based approach works better, so combining the two might make sense. Let's say a prerequisite only mentions one subject (e.g. `Prerequisite: Arabic 601C with a grade of at least C.`). Then a rule-based approach to find all course numbers (3 digits + one letter) + grade (upper case single letter in `[A, B, C, D, E, F]`) would work very well.

Comment: So you could go rule-based for easy cases or some popular/often-occuring formats (since rule-based will work nearly perfectly for them). Only if the input does not fit one of the rule-based formats you switch to a semantic model. This way you probably would minimize the overall error rate.